# Where is the edge of [edge-device]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Since it seems to be *tag review season* (judging by the amount of recent meta threads!), I think we need to consider whether [edge-device](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edge-device) is appropriate for the site, and if so, how we can improve the tag wiki and excerpt to make the meaning clear.

There is currently **no usage guidance** for [edge-device](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edge-device), but Wikipedia [does have a useful definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_device) which we could use  if we decide this tag is worth keeping. I'm not sure whether it would be better to keep this tag or just use a more specific tag for the situation - on the one hand the generality of the tag could be useful for some questions, but it does seem to make it easy to write broad questions.

Should we keep this tag and clarify it, or should it be **burninated**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure we will have a need for this tag in the future, but it probably makes sense to wait till we have questions which focus specifically on the characteristics of the edge device, rather than nodes which fit in the network at this position. I'd say that would be *concentrator* or *cache* types of function, rather than something like Alexa (which is arguably a borderline edge device).

Concepts like **fog computing** (where the processing and bandwidth is pushed out away from a central (cloud) server) might give a scenario where this tag is relevant in the future.

Comment: I hadn't considered this - your proposal for using [edge-device] for their characteristics makes much more sense. Luckily, the tag can easily be recreated since it was only burninated.

Comment: I see tags as primarily relating to the question, not the subject of the question. I think this makes them easier to define (as well as more useful).

Answer (score 2):

I have removed the tag from all questions using it, since there has been no opposition here and the term is very poorly defined. In other words,

[image: Burninated!]

Answer (score 1):

I have actually asked the creator of the tag a few days back in chat. The discussion is [around here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34185366#34185366). The problem in my view is that the tag is currently based on a non-standard definition, which is not only slightly different from the Wikipedia one, but somewhat contradictory.

Since the tag does not make any sense without a properly defined edge and it seems to me that any definition will be in the range of *a thing in the Internet of Things.* That would be horribly [meta](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for this site. The three questions all refer to an IoT end user device—*a thing*, basically.

Unless we make that *thing* a lot more specific, I'd like to get rid of the tag.